# Build user store on WSO2 IS 4.5.0

Tags: build, wso2-identity-server

I'm bit cunfused with building the WSO2 IS user store from source code.

The documentation says checkout from:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk01
and there is a turing-chunk01\carbon-platform\components\user-stores

However, the binary distribution seems to be compiled from 
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0
and there is a carbon-kernel\core\org.wso2.carbon.user.core\4.2.0\

The implementation of both user stores differes a bit. 
Besides turing-chunk01...\user-stores\org.wso2.carbon.user.store is missing a parent POM.

Is WSO2 IS intended to be compiled from carbon/kernel or turing-chunks? I would like to do few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

User kernel source of 4.5.0 release can be found at [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0/) that you have mentioned. Basically you can find user.core source from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/). If you have the change in user.core, you can modify the code,, Build it and then new jar file can be copied  to /repository/component/plugins directory and replaced the existing jar. When you restart the server you can see the new changes. 
If you want to build the all source...  then you need to build the carbon/kernel and carbon/platform also.

Comment: Thank you Asela, so I will use user store in carbon kernel. Not the one in carbon platform turing chunk.